# error: Unable to determine the type of the len parameter of the gperf hash/lookup function

Tags: aix, fontconfig, gperf

I'd like to build fontconfig library under AIX os 64 bits. So I downloaded fontconfig source and I executed the configure commande : ./configure --prefix=/home/stephv/libraries/sharedlib
configure returns the followings error:
checking The type of len parameter of gperf hash/lookup function... configure: error: Unable to determine the type of the len parameter of the gperf hash/lookup function

So, how can I resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: As a start, carefully read file `config.log`

Comment: in the config.log file I have the same error that I put in my question

Comment: Have you successfully installed FreeType2, that seems to be a dependency of fontconfig?

Comment: Not yet but I put the file freetype-2.5.0.1.so in a repository and I added this repo to the environnement variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But I wonder if the error that I get is related to the freetype2 library?

Comment: This program install you should: https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/